# HOW TO SOLVE PHP ERROR: Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool

Tags: javascript, php, html

I keep on getting this errors and i cant seem to find a solution:

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\tagopuss\core\classes\tweet.php on line 67
>
> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\tagopuss\core\classes\tweet.php on line 20
>
> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\tagopuss\core\classes\tweet.php on line 63

this is my code below

my line 20 code

```
'.(($retweet['retweetID'] === $tweet->retweetID OR $tweet->retweetID > 0) ? '
```

my line 65-68

```
<li>'.(($tweet->tweetID === $retweet['retweetID']) ? '<button class="retweeted" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'" data-user="'.$tweet->tweetBy.'"> <i class="fa fa-retweet"></i><span class="retweetsCount">'.$tweet->retweetCount.'</span>
                                </button>' : '<button class="retweet" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'" data-user="'.$tweet->tweetBy.'"> <i class="fa fa-retweet"></i><span class="retweetsCount">'.(($tweet->retweetCount > 0) ? $tweet->retweetCount : '').'</span>
                                </button>').'</li>



<?php
   class Tweet extends User {

       function __construct($pdo){
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
       }

       public function tweets($user_id){
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tweets`,`users` WHERE `tweetBy` = `user_id`");
        $stmt->execute();
        $tweets = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        foreach($tweets as $tweet){
          $likes   = $this->likes($user_id, $tweet->tweetID);
          $retweet = $this->checkRetweet($tweet->tweetID, $user_id);
          $user    = $this->userData($tweet->retweetBy);
       echo '<div class="all-tweet">
          <div class="post"> 
           <div class="t-show-inner">
           '.(($retweet['retweetID'] === $tweet->retweetID OR $tweet->retweetID > 0) ? '
            <div class="t-show-banner">
              <div class="t-show-banner-inner">
                <span><i class="fa fa-retweet" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span>'.$user->screenName.' Retweeted</span>
              </div>
            </div>' 
            : '').'



            <div class="t-show-popup">
              <div class="post-heading">
                <div class="t-show-img">
                  <img src="'.$tweet->profileImage.'"/>
                </div>
                <div class="t-s-head-content">
                  <div class="post-title">
                    <span><a href="'.$tweet->username.'">'.$tweet->screenName.'</a></span>
                    <span>@'.$tweet->username.'</span>
                    <span>'.$tweet->postedOn.'</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="post-description">
                    '.$this->getTweetLinks($tweet->status).'
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>'.

               ((!empty($tweet->tweetImage)) ? 
                ' <div class="t-show-body">
                  <div class="t-s-b-inner">
                   <div class="post-description">
                   <img src="'.$tweet->tweetImage.'" class="imagePopup"/>
                   </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!--tweet show body end-->
                ' : '').'


              </div>
            <div class="t-show-footer">
              <div class="t-s-f-right">
                <ul> 
                  <li><button><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></button></li>  

                  <li>'.(($tweet->tweetID === $retweet['retweetID']) ? '<button class="retweeted" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'" data-user="'.$tweet->tweetBy.'"> <i class="fa fa-retweet"></i><span class="retweetsCount">'.$tweet->retweetCount.'</span>
                                </button>' : '<button class="retweet" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'" data-user="'.$tweet->tweetBy.'"> <i class="fa fa-retweet"></i><span class="retweetsCount">'.(($tweet->retweetCount > 0) ? $tweet->retweetCount : '').'</span>
                                </button>').'</li>

                  <li>'.(($likes['likeOn'] === $tweet->tweetID) ? '<button class="unlike-btn" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'" data-user="'.$tweet->tweetBy.'"> <i class="fa fa-heart" area-hidden="true"></i><span class="likesCounter">'.$tweet->likesCount.'</span></button>' : '<button class="like-btn" data-tweet="'.$tweet->tweetID.'" data-user="'.$tweet->tweetBy.'"> <i class="fa fa-heart-o" area-hidden="true"></i><span class="likesCounter">'.(($tweet->likesCount > 0) ? $tweet->likesCount : '').'</span></button>' ).'</li>

                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>';
     }
     }

      public function getTrendByHash($hashtag){
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `trends` WHERE `hashtag` LIKE :hashtag LIMIT 5");
        $stmt->bindValue(':hashtag', $hashtag.'%');
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
       }

       public function getMention($mention){
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT `user_id`, `username`,`screenName`,`profileImage` FROM `users` WHERE `username` LIKE :mention OR `screenName` LIKE :mention LIMIT 5");
        $stmt->bindValue(':mention', $mention.'%');
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
       }

       public function addTrend($hashtag){
        preg_match_all("/#+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/i", $hashtag, $matches);
        if($matches){
          $result = array_values($matches[1]);
        }

        $sql  = "INSERT INTO `trends` (`hashtag`,`createdOn`) VALUES(:hashtag, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";

        foreach ($result as $trend) {
          if($stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql)){
            $stmt->execute(array(':hashtag' => $trend));
          }
        }
       }

       public function getTweetLinks($tweet){
        $tweet = preg_replace("/(https?:\/\/)([\w]+.)([\w\.]+)/", "<a href='$0' target='_blink'>$0</a>", $tweet);
        $tweet = preg_replace("/#([\w]+)/", "<a href='".BASE_URL."hashtag/$1'>$0</a>", $tweet);
        $tweet = preg_replace("/@([\w]+)/", "<a href='".BASE_URL."$1'>$0</a>", $tweet);
        return $tweet;
       }

       public function getPopupTweet($tweet_id){
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tweets`,`users` WHERE `tweetID` = :tweet_id AND `tweetBy` = `user_id`");
        $stmt->bindParam(":tweet_id", $tweet_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
       }

       public function retweet($tweet_id, $user_id, $get_id, $comment){
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("UPDATE `tweets` SET `retweetCount` = `retweetCount` +1 WHERE `tweetID` = :tweet_id");
        $stmt->bindParam(":tweet_id", $tweet_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `tweets` (`status`,`tweetBy`,`tweetImage`,`retweetID`,`retweetBy`,`postedOn`,`likesCount`,`retweetCount`,`retweetMsg`) SELECT `status`,`tweetBy`,`tweetImage`,`tweetID`,:user_id,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,`likesCount`,`retweetCount`,:retweetMsg FROM `tweets` WHERE `tweetID` = :tweet_id ");
        $stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":retweetMsg", $comment, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":tweet_id", $tweet_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
       }

       public function checkRetweet($tweet_id, $user_id){
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tweets` WHERE `retweetID` = :tweet_id AND `retweetBy` = :user_id OR `tweetID` = :tweet_id AND `retweetBy` = :user_id");
        $stmt->bindParam(":tweet_id", $tweet_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
       }

       public function addLike($user_id, $tweet_id, $get_id){
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("UPDATE `tweets` SET `likesCount` = `likesCount` +1 WHERE `tweetID` = :tweet_id");
        $stmt->bindParam(":tweet_id", $tweet_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

        $this->create('likes', array('likeBy' => $user_id, 'likeOn' => $tweet_id));
       }

       public function unlike($user_id, $tweet_id, $get_id){
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("UPDATE `tweets` SET `likesCount` = `likesCount` -1 WHERE `tweetID` = :tweet_id");
        $stmt->bindParam(":tweet_id", $tweet_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM `likes` WHERE `likeBy` = :user_id AND `likeOn` = :tweet_id");
        $stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":tweet_id", $tweet_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
       }

       public function likes($user_id, $tweet_id){
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `likes` WHERE `likeBy` =:user_id AND `likeOn` = :tweet_id");
        $stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":tweet_id", $tweet_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
       }


  }
 ?>
```

Comment: It basicly says that inside your `$retweet` array, you don't have `retweetID` if i understand correctly

Comment: It says that `$retweet` has the type boolean, not array. It means your `checkRetweet` function is returning a boolean value. Database query could return `false` if there is failture, you should always check if your database query is success before return value.

Comment: its more like an error that occured after i upgraded my php, anytime i try to use a command like this   '(($tweet->tweetID ===  $retweet['retweetID']) ? ' ' : ' ' )'     @HalilÇakar

Comment: can you help me rearrange the code or help clarify how it is suppose to be @catcon